# Bitbucket Pipeline ssh response is No such file or directory

Tags: ssh, bitbucket, devops, bitbucket-pipelines

My bitbucket pipeline code is below. I would like to know why is bitbucket ssh returning no such file or directory?

```
image: php:7.4
pipelines:
  custom:
    build-and-deploy-to-dev:
      - step:
         deployment: Test
         script:
          - echo "test"
          - pipe: "atlassian/ssh-run:0.2.4"
            variables:
              SSH_USER: ubuntu
              SERVER: ec2-12-345-678-000.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
              SSH_KEY: $SSH_KEY
              MODE: script
              COMMAND: deploy.sh
```

/pipe.sh: line 70: deploy.sh: No such file or directory

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that the `deploy.sh` script exists in the home directory of the `ubuntu` user?
Be careful because with `MODE: 'script'` **the script in your repository** will be launched, while with `MODE: 'command'` **the script already on your remote server** will be launched.

Comment: I put file in Home/Ubuntu and it worked... BTW... is there any way to execute the file from project directory? like /var/www/site/deploy.sh

Comment: Have you tried `MODE: 'command'` and `COMMAND: 'cd  /var/www/site; git pull; ./deploy.sh'`?